# Sum Column At Each Value Change of another field in foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

Sum Column At Each Value Change of another field in foxpro. How can I get the additive column? I was able to do a running total but for all the items how can I get it to start at each item change?

E.g.

```
Item Number      QTY     ADDITIVE
1045             50           50
1045             25           75
1045             35          110
2045             50           50
2045             50          100 
2045             25          125
3056             30           30
3056             30           60
3056             30           90
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what output you want?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an event that fires when a value changes. Is this something you want attached to the table for all time, or something you want to happen in a particular form?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like simple additive, but how are you planning on storing and presenting to the end-user the results... in a grid or just final running total per individual item?  It looks like this might represent sales order item / qty sold.  I would probably query into a read/write cursor ordered by item, then apply a scan loop to update each one... something like.

```
select ItemNumber, Qty, 000000 as RunningTotal ;
   from YourTable ;
   order by ItemNumber ;
   into cursor C_Sample readwrite

lastItem = ""
runTotal = 0
scan
   */ If different item, reset running total back to zero
   if lastItem != ItemNumber
      runTotal = 0
   endif
   */ Update running total   
   runTotal = runTotal + Qty
   */ Update the record column
   replace RunningTotal with runTotal
   */ preserve the ID we just processed for comparison to next record
   lastItem = ItemNumber
endscan 

*/ Done...
```